# Не работают псевдоклассы :hover и :nth-child для строк таблицы

Tags: html, css

В стилях таблицы задано:

```
tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td { background-color: #DC143C; }
tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td { background-color: #20B2AA;  }
tr:hover { background: #00BFFF; }
```

Но в IE8 не отображаются цвета четных и нечетных строк таблицы, а в Файерфоксе не работает выделение строки, на которую наведена мышка.
В чем ошибка, как это исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Селектор `nth-child` работает только с `9` версии `IE`

[htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child)

Comment: Но почему тогда в Файерфоксе не работает псевдокласс :hover ?

Comment: Насчет Файерфокса — что-то не так в другом куске стилей, т.к. в чистом виде `td:hover` работает без проблем.

Comment: Извините, там в приведенном куске кода была ошибка, сейчас я её уже исправила, должно быть tr:hover.
Но сути дела это не меняет, ни для ячейки, ни для строки в Файерфоксе это не работает.

Comment: Судя по всему, эти псевдоклассы противоречат друг другу, tr:hover работает, если из стилей выкинуть tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td { background-color: #DC143C; } tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td { background-color: #20B2AA;  }.

А как тогда их совместить?

Comment: у меня в `MF 10.0.2` — работает, выделяются парные/непарные строки. Может у Вас старая версия браузера? Если же нет, попробуйте вместо `2n` и `2n+1` использовать `even` и `odd`.

Comment: У меня тоже MF 10.0.2. 
Я говорю о том, что эти два псевдокласса - :hover и :nth-child не работают одновременно. Если я убираю один из них, то другой работает.
Я хочу добиться одновременной их работы, но не знаю как.

Comment: стоп.. понял в чем ошибка. Вы ставите `:hover` на саму строку, тоесть там фон меняется, но он не виден, т.к. фон ячеек, стоящих "выше" перекрывает их. По-идее, всё решится при добавлении `tr:hover` *`td`*.

Тоесть так:

    tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td {background-color:#DC143C}
    tbody tr:nth-child(2n) td {background-color:#20B2AA}
    tr:hover td {background:#00BFFF}

Answer (score 1):

делайте это на **jQuery**, **ИЕ** не воспринимает многие селекторы и псевдоклассы.